# Using Embedded Kafka for testing Kafka Streams application

Tags: spring-kafka

We are evaluating if we can use Embedded Kafka for testing our streams app. Can we achieve the below using embedded kafka:

- Use KafkaTestUtils to produce the message to the input topic running on Embedded Kafka.
- Expect the streams application to pick up the message for processing (should the application be running for this ?)
- Use KafkaTestUtils to consume the processed message from output topic.
- Assert the expected condition.

Please let me know.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; you can do that.

There are examples in the framework tests https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/main/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/streams

Comment: My stream is not coming to running status ( seems to be in rebalancing mode). And seeing "illegal state exception" when using a consumer to get the data from output topic. Can you please let me know how to check why the stream is not coming to running status ? Thanks

Comment: I can't speculate. I suggest you ask a new question showing your code and the logs.